# How do you negate having to have a second SSL certificate for a parked domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

**This is the scenario:**
There is a valid SSL certificate configured in Apache for www.example.ac.za.
There is a parked domain of www.example.co.za without a valid SSL certificate.

To avoid having to purchase two certificates the client would like the .co.za to redirect to .ac.za. I understand (and have found) that this can not be done in the .htaccess as the presentation of the SSL certificate is done first.

Can one turn SSL off for .co.za but have it remain on for .ac.za? Would this resolve the problem?

**Additional Info**
These domains are configure in Apache as VirtualHosts with their own .conf and ssl.conf files.

Redirects are done to make sure the root of these domains end up at https://www.example.ac.za

Would appreciate some insight pls :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can one turn SSL off for .co.za but have it remain on for .ac.za? Would this resolve the problem?

You can remove the SSL vhost for `.co.za` so if someone attempts to go to `https://www.example.co.za` they'd get a site not found. But if you want *anything* to appear when they go to the https website for `.co.za`, then there **must** be something listening to the SSL port (443) that expects requests for the `.co.za` domain. And like you understand, in order to do that, you need a valid certificate unless you're ok with the security exception.

The other thing you can do is buy a single cert for both domains. There's nothing else you can do in the server/vhost configs. Doesn't matter if it's htaccess or not, a redirect happens after a successful SSL handshake.

Comment: Kewl, makes total sense! Thanks boss :)